# sql need performant polymorphic inline table value function

Tags: sql, performance, polymorphism

I need to achieve performant polymorphic inline table valued functions in sql in some way shape or form.

My current approach is as follows.  It does NOT perform well.  In my actual code I have on the order of 50-100 different types.

```
create table things (
    id int identity primary key,
    typecode int
)

create function foo_type1()
returns table
as return
    select id, v = 'blah1' 
    from things

create function foo_type2()
returns table
as return
    select id, v = 'blah2' 
    from things

create function foo_type3()
returns table
as return
    select id, v = 'blah3' 
    from things


create function foo_poly()
return table
as return    
select
    f.*
from things t
join (
    select typecode=1, * from foo_type1()
    union all select typecode=2, * from foo_type2()
    union all select typecode=3, * from foo_type3()
) f on f.typecode = t.typecode
```

My typical query is for a small subset of rows, eg

```
select * from foo_poly() where id in (123, 912, 2312)
select * from foo_poly() where id = 123
```

My `things` table has around 2.5 million (small) rows.

My actual values (`v` columns) are more complex than selecting a constant and must be computed dynamically.

The select query is taking way too long (~10 seconds).

I have tried a bunch of things (left joins+coalesce was WAY worse) but am out of ideas.

Comment: select * from foo_type1/2/3() where id = 123 is fast?

Comment: fairly fast.  i was in fact able to workaround the slowness be speeding up the foo_type1/2/3s but it still seems like it's doing a lot of querying across all types instead of (ideally) across the specific types needed